# Task Scheduler will not start

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler

When I open it from Computer Management

[image]

However the service appears to be running

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc query Schedule

SERVICE_NAME: Schedule
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

When I open Task Scheduler by itself

[image]
[image]

Text of the error

```
FX:{c7b8fb06-bfe1-4c2e-9217-7a69a95bbac4}
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Exception type: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Exception stack trace:
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.MmcThreadMessageWindow.OnThreadException(Exception e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.MessageBox(HandleRef hWnd, String text, String caption, Int32 type)
   at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, String text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options, Boolean showHelp)
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Advanced.MessageBoxParameters.ShowDialog(IWin32Window parent)
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.ConsoleDialogHost.ShowDialog(WaitCursor waitCursor, ShowDialogCallback callback)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ManagementUI.CombinedControls.MMCConsole.ShowDialog(MessageBoxParams messageParams)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ManagementUI.CombinedControls.DisplayError.UserError(String errorString)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ManagementUI.CombinedControls.UITaskBase.ShowServiceIsDownMessage(Exception e, Boolean restartService)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ManagementUI.CombinedControls.UITaskFolder.GetUITaskList(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs eWorker, Boolean loadTaskDefinitions, Boolean includeHiddenTasks)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ManagementUI.CombinedControls.TaskDetailControl.EnumerateTasksAndAddToList()
   at Microsoft.Windows.ManagementUI.CombinedControls.TaskDetailControl.RefreshData(Boolean firstRefresh)
   at Microsoft.Windows.ManagementUI.CombinedControls.TaskDetailControl.InitializeTaskDetailControl()
   at Microsoft.TaskScheduler.SnapIn.TaskSchedFolderFormViewControl.Microsoft.ManagementConsole.IFormViewControl.Initialize(FormView snapinFormView)
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.FormView.InternalInitialize()
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.View.HandleInitializationRequest(IRequestStatus requestStatus)
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.View.ProcessRequest(Request request)
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.ViewMessageClient.ProcessRequest(Request request)
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.IMessageClient.ProcessRequest(Request request)
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.RequestStatus.BeginRequest(IMessageClient messageClient, RequestInfo requestInfo)
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.SnapInRequestOperation.ProcessRequest()
   at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.Operation.OnThreadTransfer(SimpleOperationCallback callback)
```

My machine was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and the error did not occur on Windows 7. This is the first time I have tried to open Task Scheduler on Windows 10.

Additionally, `sfc /scannow` reports no problems

Other MMC snap-ins appear to be working correctly.

Comment: Look at this script here and see if that helps: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Repair-CorruptedTampered-c8d2e975 (appears to require SETACL and REG.exe if you don't have already) otherwise here is another post with a **PSEXEC -i -s CMD** and **SC CONFIG SCHEDULE start= auto** http://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/49136-error-task-scheduler-service-not-available.html... just be sure to run command prompt elevated as administrator first.

Comment: Check this out.... **I deleted these 2 keys and exported them first and it works perfect every time....
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks` and                                        
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tree`**. . . [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/task-scheduler-service-is-not-available-task/cd3b2be4-4206-4ae1-81dd-ef29e3bc9ae1?page=2)